# Could an aluminum housing and passive cooling interfere with SoC's functioning?

Tags: wifi, interference, board

I took the board out of a broken tablet. The SoC on the board gets hot pretty quickly. I thought about fixing the board to an aluminum plate, so that it touches the SoC and disctributes its heat, and by the way is a simple "one-sided casing".

Would that interfere with the SoC, or the whole computers functioning? (eg: WiFi)

Comment: Out of curiosity, how was the SoC heatsunk in the original tablet?

Comment: @ Nick Alexeev: there was none, the original tablet casing became hot in near the SoC in about 10 minutes of use (it's a cheap one, I guess they saved on this design factor)

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if there was a designed-in contact patch between the SoC and the case. That way, the case is the heat sink. Cheap and effective as long as you don't hold it in your lap.

Answer (score 1):

Should be OK provided that:

- you don't short out anything with the plate
- the plate has a good thermal connection to the SoC (thermal paste, securely held)
- the plate is kept clear of the WiFi antenna (signals can't go through plate, or PCB ground plane)